# How do I horizontally align my li's in an ul element?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering

my problem is that I can't figure out, no matter what i try, why the `<li>` doesn't want to center. Note: by center, I mean make the three `<li>`'s horizontally center in the my `<div>` element. 
**My Code:**

```
<div class="bottomBar" id="bottomBar">
    <ul class="bottomUl">
        <li>
            <span onclick="contactMe ();"> Contact Me </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span> Help </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span> Social Media </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
.bottomBar {margin-left: 18.0%; height: 80px; background-color: #555555; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px black; bottom: 0;}
.bottomUl {color: white; width: 10%; list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; display: block;}
.bottomUl li span {font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';}
.buttonUl li {height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;}
.bottomUl span:hover {cursor: pointer; color: red; text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px black;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your css of `ul` should be changed a bit.
Remove `width:10%` and add `text-align:center` and `padding:0` to `ul`.

```
.bottomUl {
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;}
```

The above solution will center the `li` in the middle vertically

**EDIT : 1**

If you want all `li`'s to be on the same row. You need to explore `flex` in CSS. Your css should be like following for `ul`

```
.bottomUl {
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;}
```

The above CSS will center the `li`'s center. The `justify-content` property will help you place the elements as per your need in flex.

The following CSS will put space around the `li`'s in the flex.

```
.bottomUl {
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;}
```

The following CSS will put space between the `li`'s. If you use `space-between` the flex items.

```
.bottomUl {
   color: white;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;}
```

The following CSS will space the `li`'s evenly. If you use `space-evenly` property to `justify-content`

```
.bottomUl {
   color: white;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-evenly;}
```

I would like to suggest to explore `flex` box more in the following link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

For cross-browser compatibility. Please visit the following link, whether it meets you need
https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Hope this answer will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much did the job, the only problem I am experiencing now is the fact that the <li> elements are under each other when I want them on the same row.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I didn't consider placing li's in same row. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this did the job, much love for the effort you put in thus you get the answer mark. Also, I know a little bit about flex box but you are right that becoming an expert will allow me to style my websites very nicely and so I will check your link out. Once again thank you, and have a wonderful day :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this css.

```
.bottomBar {margin-left: 18.0%; height: 80px; background-color: #555555; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px black; bottom: 0;}
.bottomUl {color: white; width: 100%; list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; display: block; text-align: center;}
.bottomUl li span {font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';}
.bottomUl li {height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;}
.bottomUl span:hover {cursor: pointer; color: red; text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px black;}
```

What I did:

- Changed '.buttonUl li' to '.bottomUl li'
- Changed 'width: 10%;' to 'width: 100%;' under .bottomUl
- Added 'text-align: center;' under .bottomUl

Comment: This was a nice try to center them but unfortunately the centering is very sloppy and doesn't look nice at all, on the other hand there was improvement since the elements did move and change position so I will start working from there and see if I can fix it my self. Don't worry, ill post the answer afterwords!

Answer (score 0):

To make elements centered you need to use `margin: auto` css property.
Just check the example code below. The div will be centered within it's parent and will take 80% width. The same will happen with the ul element.

```
div{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
}
ul{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

If you want it really centered, please make sure you remember of default CSS properties for DOM elements:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Within Default CSS Values for HTML Elements, focus on margin and padding.
To have full control on layout, just use following:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

The all * selector will make sure to set padding and margin to 0 for all of your elements.

I wonder why `margin: auto;` does not work on li elemets. I figured out the solution for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        div {
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: blue;
            width: 32%;

        }

        ul {
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: purple;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bottomBar" id="bottomBar">
        <ul class="bottomUl">
            <li>
                <span onclick="contactMe ();"> Contact Me </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span> Help </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span> Social Media </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added the specified css you said but it didn't do anything? By the way, it would be more helpful for you to list the 'Default CSS Values' instead of linking them, please edit your post and do so, you might get some thicks up as well as be more helpful to me!

Comment: I added the working solution for you. "You can set the margin property to auto to horizontally center the element within its container." I wonder why it does not work on li elements. It does on every other. We need to investigate it.

Comment: I already found a solution and marked it a little further down, it works for me but you are right that investigating why it doesn't work on the li elements will be interesting, so "Just Do It" :D